# How can I force the console to output to something other than the framebuffer?

Tags: console, tty, framebuffer

I recently recompiled my kernel to support the vesa framebuffer for some Directfb fun but now my console outputs text very slowly. It's almost as if turning on the framebuffer caused my console to stop using whatever graphics driver it was before and instead output using the fb. I've searched all around my system for various tty or console configuration files with no prevail.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in the `grub` configuration (requires a reboot to apply the changes).

Further reading:

- [How to disable the Linux frame buffer if it's causing problems](http://kb.digium.com/articles/FAQ/How-to-disable-the-Linux-frame-buffer-if-it-s-causing-problems)
- [Disable framebuffer from Grub Meno or Launch ubuntu comand line](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429892)
- [5. Disabling the Unaccelerated Framebuffer](http://www.telecom.otago.ac.nz/tele301/student_html/sysinst-disable-framebuffer.html)

Comment: Well I don't necessarily want to disable the framebuffer. I would still like to use it for programming purposes but I would like the console to output using something other than the framebuffer.

Comment: @user3211355 sort of unrelated, but what are you using framebuffer for to program ?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity really. I'm in the process of exploring and trying to learn the low level aspects of linux.

Comment: If you want to do that, you're better off setting up two machines, and using ssh to connect into your experimental machine.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly the same as user3211355: leave the framebuffer enabled, but just don't have the console output going into it.

Took me quite a while, but found it in the end: fbcon was modprobed somewhere. Removing that fixed it for me.